# Attr binding after an AJAX call (knockoutjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

### The goal

Invoke the `attr` binding of KnockoutJS after an AJAX call.

### The problem

Take a look on the following fragment:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Products/List?Output=JSON",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, product) {

            var item = {
                "id": product.id,
                "name": product.name,
                "slug": product.slug,
                "unitsQuantity": 
                    product.quantity + " " + 
                    (product.quantity > 1 ? 
                        product.measure + "s" : 
                        product.measure),
                "isAdded": true
            };

            viewmodel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(item);
            self.items.push(viewmodel);
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, it is a simple AJAX call that pushes information from JSON to an Knockout's array that works perfectly.

Meanwhile, in HTML...

```
<div class="product-summary-description">
    <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': slug }, text: name"></a>
</div>
```

Can you see the `data-bind="[...]"` attribute? If so, here's the problem. When I loads the page, the `href`'s attribute it isn't rendered on the element (in my case, `a`'s element).

What can I do?

Yes, I can imagine that the problem is something related with the script calling sequence, but I can't see a light to resolve this issue. Someone can give me an idea — at least for start?

Comment: Can you post more view code ? Is the name shown properly ?

Comment: @Damien Yes, the name is showing properly. Hang on a second while I post a bit more code.

Comment: Have you checked the data (the product.slug) ? Or the created viewmodel ?

Comment: BTW the "a" needs a text bniding to have clickable text.

Comment: Try to bind the text to the slug so you verify that the slug property is ok.

Comment: "Have you checked the data (the product.slug)?" No, I haven't — was my fault. Want to convert your comment into an answer to me for accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the data (the product.slug) ?

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the ticks from your href as in

data-bind="attr: { href: slug }, text: name"